# change one color in an image to another

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to convert just green color to red in an image. I've written the code below but it doesn't work correctly

```
   rgbImage = imread('image.jpg');
   [rows columns numberOfColorBands] = size(rgbImage);
   imshow(rgbImage, []);
   title('Original Color Image');
   redChannel = rgbImage(:, :, 1);
   greenChannel = rgbImage(:, :, 2);
   blueChannel = rgbImage(:, :, 3);
   rgbImage2 = cat(3, greenChannel, redChannel, blueChannel);
   imshow(rgbImage2, []);
   title('Green is now red');
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code **swap** Red color channel and Green color channel.

`rgbImage2 = cat(3, greenChannel, redChannel, blueChannel);`
Put green in place of red, and red in place of green (swap channels).

In order to keep green color channel unchanged, and replace (original) red with green, use the following:
`rgbImage2 = cat(3, greenChannel, greenChannel, blueChannel);`

Result for `peppers.png` image:

```
rgbImage = imread('peppers.png');
[rows columns numberOfColorBands] = size(rgbImage);
imshow(rgbImage, []);
title('Original Color Image');
redChannel = rgbImage(:, :, 1);
greenChannel = rgbImage(:, :, 2);
blueChannel = rgbImage(:, :, 3);
rgbImage2 = cat(3, greenChannel, greenChannel, blueChannel);
imshow(rgbImage2, []);
title('Green is now red');
```

[image]

Original image:
[image]

Comment: Funnily, that photo looks unmodified!

Answer (score 1):

As Rotem said, you are just swapping red and green channels. Swapping affects to whole image instead of just green colors.

One has to segment out green color first to change green color to any other color. You can find couple of [examples](https://in.mathworks.com/help/images/examples.html#segmentation-test) in Matlab documentation itself.

I have tried to segment and change the green color, below code might not work on your image, but it's possible to get decent results I guess.

```
 rgbImage = imread('peppers.png');
 figure, imshow(rgbImage);
 title('Original Image');

 redChannel = rgbImage(:, :, 1);
 greenChannel = rgbImage(:, :, 2);
 blueChannel = rgbImage(:, :, 3);

 %% Now lets take the difference of each the channels. 
 % these subtracted images will be used to mask the segmented area.
 % If you are curious, plot them and see how they look!! 
 red_subtract_grn = redChannel-greenChannel;
 red_subtract_blue = redChannel-blueChannel;
 grn_subtract_blue = greenChannel - blueChannel;
 red_add_grn = double(redChannel)+double(greenChannel)+double(blueChannel);

 %% Lets segment the green color by filtering/thresholding technique,
 % we need to choose the index number according to rgbImage, one should tweak a bit to get better results. (These
 % numbers worked well for 'peppers.jpg' image.I have used indexing since its 
 % very neat and faster, alternatively you can use find() also).
 try_mask = ones(size(rgbImage(:,:,1))); %Initialize mask image.
 try_mask(red_subtract_blue < 7) = 0;    %remove background
 try_mask = medfilt2(try_mask,[4,4]);    %Filter unwanted scattered pixels.
 try_mask(red_subtract_grn > 40) = 0;
 try_mask(red_add_grn > 500) = 0;
 try_mask(grn_subtract_blue < 20) = 0;
 try_mask(blueChannel > 80) = 0;
 try_mask = medfilt2(try_mask,[8,8]);

 %% Lets apply mask to remove green and blue pixels such that only red color will appear on the masked region.
 greenChannel(try_mask > 0) = 0;
 blueChannel(try_mask > 0) = 0;
 rgbImage2 = cat(3, redChannel, greenChannel, blueChannel);

 figure, imshow(rgbImage2);
 title('After changing green to red')
```

green color to red color:

[image: img]